# Catching the event when system volume is manipulated

Tags: vb.net-2010

Im trying to catch the event when the user decreases or increases the system volume of the laptop. I've tried searching the net and found this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370892(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316531(VS.85).aspx

But I dont know the syntax in using it. Could you please help me.